# How to use parameter expansion with find -exec {}?

Tags: shell-script, find, exec, parameter, bash-expansion

I want to incorporate something like:

```
for f in */*; do mv "$f" "${f%/*}/foo.${f##*.}"; done
```

Into my `find x -exec y {} \;`-style workflow.

The `for` loop construct & `"$f"` variable will likely be omitted; the loop will be substituted by standard `-exec` iterating behaviour, and the variable (containing the filename of the current iteration), by `{}`.
But it seems like these two different syntaxes are incompatible/problematic. Especially because of the conflicting braces and semicolons, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-exec bash -c 'your code here using $0'`.

In your case, this one

```
find */* -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%/*}/foo.${0##*.}"' {} \;
```

is very similar to your `for`.

```
for f in */*; do        mv "$f" "${f%/*}/foo.${f##*.}"; done
```

Tip 1: You can also use `-exec sh -c '.....'` in case you are not using bash.

Tip 2: You can combine more than one `-exec` under the same find:

```
find ./* -type f -exec echo {} \; -exec cat {} \;
```

Tip 3: For simple constructs this syntax is valid:

```
find . -type f  ! -name "*.txt" -exec mv -v '{}' '{}'.txt \;
```

Tip 4: Instead of `-exec` you can use `-ok` which asks for user confirmation before running the command (useful for testing)

Above works in GNU `find` (I have version 4.6.0),
but I am not sure if all those tips work in other `find` implementations.

Comment: You do not seem to know that `{}` needs to be the whole argument in order to be expanded. You cannot append or prepend text to that argument. See your tip #3

Comment: @schily My `gnu find 4.6.0` works perfectly with synthax provided in tip 3. For example ths works fine : `find . -maxdepth 1 -exec echo '{}' '{}'.txt \;`. Maybe you are using a non gnu find.

Comment: @schily even this one works ok: `find . -maxdepth 1 -exec echo newtexthere'{}'.txt \;`

Comment: GNU find is not find...(it gnu find e.g. more than 20 years to implement the standard -exec + feature) other find implementations expand only separate {} args.

Comment: @schily ok. Sorry, i have only gnu find.

Comment: (1a) It should be noted that, if you say `-exec prog1 {} ';' -exec prog2 {} ';'`, then `prog2` will be executed only if `prog1` exits with status 0. (1b) I don’t understand why you’re even mentioning `-exec echo {} \; -exec cat {} \;`, as I don’t see how you’re using it to solve *this* problem (renaming). (1c) `-exec echo {} \;` is equivalent to `-print`. (2a) To search the current directory and all sub-directories under it, recursively, it’s best to say simply `find .`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  When you specify a glob as the first argument (e.g., ``find ./*`` or ``find */*``), you’re forcing *the shell* to expand that glob. Like `ls *`, this is redundant when you’re invoking a program that already knows how to enumerate directories. (2b) Unless you have set `dotglob`, `find ./*` (and `find */*`) will overlook top-level files and directories whose names begin with **`.`**. (2c) Whenever you use a glob, you run the risk of generating a command line that’s longer than the maximum.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … This is a fairly low risk now that ```ARG_MAX``` is [commonly 10000 or more, sometimes as high as 100000 or 1000000](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax#results), so commands like `cat *` are probably safe from this pitfall. But when you’re invoking a program that already knows how to enumerate directories (e.g., `find`, `ls`, `chmod`, `cp`, `grep`, `rm`, …), why take the risk? (Note that some of us can remember [when `ARG_MAX` was 512](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/man/man2/exec.2).)